# reading indexed palette image in C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

My platform is Windows. I didn't expect reading indexed palette image to be this difficult in C++. In case you are not familiar with it, it's single channel image but expresses its pixel color with 256 indexed colors called palette.

I was using OpenCV but its imread just converts the file to a 3 channel image so I have no way to save it back to indexed palette image or compare it with another indexed palette image.

I tried to use Bitmap but for some reason, it does not read correct pixel values.

So right now, I am looking for a light library or code to read pixels from indexed palette file.

Comment: Which `Bitmap` do you mean? If you mean [GDI+'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534420(v=vs.85).aspx) then it can handle indexed images just fine. Maybe you should show the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: If you're using Win7+, [WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902(v=vs.85).aspx) has native support for TIFF decoding and encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OpenCV to read or write a image from real cameras will lose and change the image information, so I prefer to use gdi+, which is more powerful in dealing with image format problems to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As comments on the question shows, I decided to have two methods, OpenCV for non-indexed-palette images and Bitmap (GDI+) for indexed palette images. Now everything is working perfect.